# Why didn't Newton pursue philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, newton

Why didn't he pursue philosophy in the same way Leibniz did, many "natural philosophers" during that time often delved into many fields since it wasn't really required to specialize yet, but it seems like Newton did not care for philosophy or the philosophical questions that his contemporaries like Leibniz, Spinoza etc. answered. He seemed to be more interested in theology?

any reason for this

Comment: Theology and considerations about space where effectively metaphysics, and thus considered "Philosophy". (Empirical) physics and theology parted ways with philosophy (also regarding institutions/faculties in universities) much later on. Kant wrote a whole book essentially criticising Newtonian "philosophy" (metaphysics). So what exactly makes you think he did not write philosophy? Btw I consider Leibniz much better an example than Spinoza.

Comment: Although his emphasis was different from than that of Leibniz, Newton's studies are often referred to as *natural philosophy.* He considered this a subject which was intimately connected with theology: "[F]or Newton there was no cognitive wall between the study of God and His Creation. In the end, it is only with a sense of awkwardness and artificiality that we can continue to speak about interaction between two elements of a grand project that was for Newton a unified whole." (Stephen D. Snobelen)

Comment: He did. He pursued [natural philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_philosophy); see [Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica (1687)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophi%C3%A6_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica).

Comment: Newton could not avoid philosophy but I'd agree that he made little of it. The reason may have been his religious convictions, which enmired him in theological questions and hobbled his philosophy. Leibnitz was a freer-thinker so had more thinking-space. Strong but unverified religious beliefs do not help us in philosophy.